# Parse a string of floats in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
list=[['10, 0.01, 0.0428, 120; 30, 0.1, 2, 33; 50, 0.023, 0.31, 0.65'],
      ['10, 0.7, 0.5428, 2.31'],
      ['50, 0.3, 0.35, 0.1'],
      ['-10, 0.2, 0.048, 124; -30, 0.11, 24, 3; -50, 0.02, 0.1, 0.60; 0, 0, 0, 0; 10, 0.1, 2, 33; 
       20, 0.023, 0.31, 0.66']]

df=pd.DataFrame(list)
```

I have a dataframe df from which I am trying to get the 3rd value after each semicolon sign if the column name matches with the 1st value after the semicolon sign. The expected output is as below. Any clue on how to tackle this in a simple way?

[image]

Comment: There's no semicolon in the 2nd and 3rd rows.

Comment: In that case simply need to take 3rd value

Comment: How did you get this list? Yes you can parse the floats, but you probably want to fix the source

Comment: I don't think I understand the question ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the actual data is a dataframe of 1000s of rows saved locally on my system, i have replicated a few rows in a list so people can copy and try on their system

Comment: @CutePoison i am trying to get 3rd value after semicolon and the column name should be the first value

Comment: You're getting the data *from* a dataframe? Can you post a sample of the dataframe, and whatever code you're using to extract this data?

Answer (score 1):

Use nested loops:

```
d = {}
for r, i in enumerate(l):
    for j in i[0].split(';'):
        k = j.split(',')
        c, v = int(k[0]), float(k[2])
        d[(r, c)] = v

df = pd.Series(d).unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   -50   -30    -10   0       10    20   30    50
0  0.0   0.0  0.000  0.0  0.0428  0.00  2.0  0.31
1  0.0   0.0  0.000  0.0  0.5428  0.00  0.0  0.00
2  0.0   0.0  0.000  0.0  0.0000  0.00  0.0  0.35
3  0.1  24.0  0.048  0.0  2.0000  0.31  0.0  0.00
```

Comment: OP wants the third item, which is `k[2]`!

Comment: @ddejohn You really pay more attention than me :) Thanks.

Comment: @RahulKumar. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: You always answer a hair faster than me lol, it's the least I can do to get back at you for beating me to the punch.

Comment: @ddejohn. I will not do it again, I promise :)

Comment: @Corralien the output doesn't seem to be consistent. Row 2 include the value for the last column. It should have been part of a new row. Total there should be 4 rows